# Group by aggregate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
ID       Name     Batch      Marks     Grade
1          A       2010       43         C 
2          B       2011       88         A
3          C       2011       89         A
4          D       2010       47         C
5          E       2011       82         A
```

Using R language, I need to take aggregate of the marks of students for the individual batches.
What can I use as Rollup function is not available any more in R? I really dont know how to start. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the function `aggregate`?

Comment: Package slam is outdated from version 3.0.2.

Comment: this is not `rollup` operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***aggregate*** is a good choice here.

```
with(nameOfYourDataFrame, aggregate(X=Marks, by=list(Batch), FUN=sum))
```

aggregate takes three arguments:

**X**: the continuous variable, and what's passed to the function, FUN

**by**: one or more discrete variables (aka *factors*), the values of which determine the 'partitions' that the function, FUN, evaluates

**FUN**: the function which is passed the continuous variable, X, and calculates one result for each value (or level) for each discrete variable passed in for the parameter, *by*

not sure from context what rollup function you have in mind; in any event, if it is not *sum*, then any built-in, eg *mean* or user-defined fn will work

the function *summarize* in the package **Hmisc** is another function to do the same thing.

Comment: Even I was confused if rollup function was the right was to go. Aggregate works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate with multi columns

```
V1 <- aggregate(V[,4:5], by = list(V$DESCRIPTION), sum)
```