# R: Sum every n rows of one column of data frame

Tags: r, sum, tidyverse

I am looking to sum every 5 rows of data in a column of a data frame (data) to show the sum of the previous 5 rows on the 6th row (see table below). I've tried the following dplyr which returns the sums of all total values in the overall row, rate2 column as a vector.

```
data$rate2<-
  ifelse(data$age!="Overall", data$rate,
  ifelse(data$age=="Overall",
       data %>%
       group_by(data$state,data$year)%>%
       summarise_at(vars(rate),
                     sum, na.rm=TRUE),
 ifelse(data$age,is.na(), NA)))
```

This code returns the following results:

```
State    Age         Year    rate     rate2
GA        5          2015     .4        .4
GA        6          2015     .4        .4
GA        7          2015     .5        .5
GA        8          2015     .2        .2
GA        9          2015     .3        .3
GA        Overall    2015              c(1.8,7.5)
GA        5          2016     1.0      1.0
GA        6          2016     2.0      2.0
GA        7          2016      .5       .5
GA        8          2016     1.0      1.0
GA        9          2016     3.0      3.0
GA        Overall    2016              c(1.8,7.5)
```

Is there a method to calculate a single value in the rate2 column for the "overall" rows. I'm not sure if this can be better achieved though the use of a loop. For clarity, I need to be able to use the value in the "Overall" row of the rate2 column to perform a subsequent calculation for another column.

```
State    Age         Year    rate     rate2
GA        5          2015     .4        .4
GA        6          2015     .4        .4
GA        7          2015     .5        .5
GA        8          2015     .2        .2
GA        9          2015     .3        .3
GA        Overall    2015              1.8
GA        5          2016     1.0      1.0
GA        6          2016     2.0      2.0
GA        7          2016      .5       .5
GA        8          2016     1.0      1.0
GA        9          2016     3.0      3.0
GA        Overall    2016              7.5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your input data in `dput(data)` format?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to make it a column instead of new rows?

Comment: check out [`zoo::rollsum`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-3/topics/rollmean)

Comment: If you first make an id column for the groups, then groupingsets could probably do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759773

Comment: Sorry, but this would be horrible. Always aim for tidy data. @Frank's suggestion is the way to go if you feel you have to have it this way.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a strange structure of data. However, if I understand it correctly you need to get the "Overall" value for each year to do some subsequent tasks, then with an assumed dataframe:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

data <- fread ("
           State    Age         Year    rate     rate2
           GA        5          2015     .4        .4
           GA        6          2015     .4        .4
           GA        7          2015     .5        .5
           GA        8          2015     .2        .2
           GA        9          2015     .3        .3
           GA        Overall    2015     NA       NA
           GA        5          2016     1.0      1.0
           GA        6          2016     2.0      2.0
           GA        7          2016      .5       .5
           GA        8          2016     1.0      1.0
           GA        9          2016     3.0      3.0
           GA        Overall    2016     NA       NA 
           ")

data %>% 
  filter(Age != "Overall") %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarize(Overall = sum(rate2, na.rm = T))
```